# Does a UK citizen with US residency need any paperwork to travel to UK and back?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, uk-citizens, us-residents

My son holds a UK passport.  He is married to an american girl and has a daughter and has lived in America for around 15 years. He is a legal resident. What paperwork does he need to travel to the UK for 10 days and then back to the USA ?

Answer (score 28):

To travel to the UK, your son will need his UK passport. For travel from the UK back to the US, he will need his UK passport and his US green card. No other travel paperwork should be necessary.

The only exception might be if his daughter is under 18, and he were to travel with his daughter but without his wife. Additional paperwork might be needed to prove his wife gave permission for him to travel with his daughter. This would not be necessary if he travels alone or with his whole family.

Comment: Why would he need consent from his wife to travel with his own daughter?

Comment: @SirHawrk Many countries wish to prevent international child abduction and may either require a letter of permission or a court order, or look more closely into the situation when a child is travelling with only one adult or with u related adults.

Comment: @SirHawrk In order to make sure that she has agreed to the daughter travelling with him.

Comment: The UK Border Force has published [a relevant document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/224634/Children_travelling_to_the_UK_leaflet_A5_WEB_final.pdf), which states *inter alia,* "If you are travelling with a child (under 18) and **are not the child’s parent,** or **may appear not to be the parent** (for example, if you have a different family name), we may ask you a few questions to establish your relationship with the child." (My emphasis)

Comment: When my in-laws have taken our daughters on holiday to Portugal, officers at both ends have been very strict on looking at these permissions documents - just to ensure our children were not being kidnapped/trafficked

Answer (score 5):

I myself am a UK citizen with a US residency and I've been travelling to the UK and back with a UK passport and my green card for 5 years. I want to advise in case your son is not vaccinated to get a test, since after it was announced that the UK no longer requires tests/vax status, they asked me for those. I also advise in case your son wants to get a citizenship in the future to not leave for more than a year as this may be a reason to reject the application.

Comment: any specific vaccinations, or just in general?

Comment: not sure, you should double-check with your carrier (UK gov will say you don't need anything to fly there)